# Can a Beholder include itself in its Antimagic Cone?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, antimagic-field

The beholder emits an Antimagic Cone:

> The beholder's central eye creates an area of
>   antimagic, as in the [antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell, in a 150-foot cone. At the
>   start of each of its turns, the beholder decides which way the cone
>   faces and whether the cone is active. The area works against the
>   beholder's own eye rays.

According to the [Basic Rule, Ch. 10, Cone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cone):

> A cone extends in a direction you choose from its point of
>   origin. A cone's width at a given point along its length is equal to
>   that point's distance from the point of origin. A cone's area of
>   effect specifies its maximum length.
>
> A cone's point of origin is not included in the cone's area of effect,
>   unless you decide otherwise.

Can a beholder chose to include itself in its Antimagic Cone? Would that make it effectively immune to harmful spells like [Blindness/Deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness)?

Comment: Are you playing on a grid? If so, which set of rules are you using to determine the point of origin and affected regions for come shaped effects (PHB, DMG, *Xanathar's*, which has multiple)?

Comment: @Medix2 Yes, we are using a grid. However, I wasn't aware that PHB, DMG, and XGE had different sets of grid rules. How do they differ, and how would those differences affect the answer?

Comment: I can't find the question but this is a duplicate.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Can a Beholder face its Antimagic Cone behind itself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154589)"

Comment: There are questions about whether you include yourself in the cone that this would be a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3):

The rules you just quoted say yes, so barring a DM decision otherwise, a beholder can effectively antimagic itself at will. Granted antimagic only *suppresses* magical effects, it does not remove them. So while the beholder can "turn off" your blindness/deafness, it will have to shut down any spellcasting or other magic of its own in order to do so, and in order to resume casting spells it would have to let your blindness spell come back into effect in order to do so.

Comment: When exactly does a Beholder get to choose to do this? It doesn't ever choose the point of origin for the antimagic cone; it always originates from the central eye.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure that's correct. Just because the eye creates it doesn't mean the central eye is the point of origin (and where even is the central eye anyway?) Regardless of that though, a creature can opt to include the point of origin in the spell's effect so wouldn't that simply make the Beholder included in the area?

Comment: @Medix2 Normally, yes, when casting a spell, a creature can opt to include the point of origin in the effect. But this _isn't a spell_. It never gets cast.

Comment: @Mark That seems a rather absurd conclusion to say that all the rules on areas of effects (technically in the Spellcasting chapter) apply only and exclusively to spells and not any of the other many many area effects

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't behave like an area of effect in other ways, just that casting a spell provides a procedure for choosing the point of origin, which can be included the area of effect or not. The Beholder doesn't do that procedure; it just gets to turn the field on or off and rotate it.

Comment: Good points both. There are times when the beholder may want to include itself, and other times when it may not. This is a grey area in the rules. I propose two solutions: 1) the choice occurs when the beholder turns the cone on (if it is already on, he has to turn it off first) OR 2) he can choose at the start of each turn to include or exclude himself. There may not be a RAW answer to which is correct.